# Latex Notation in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, latex

Oddly I cannot get Latex parsing correctly in WP. So wordpress now supports natively latex but it seems that I am struggling with some basic latex examples, that work without any errors. For example using the following code works:

```
$latex i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left|\Psi(t)\right>=H\left|\Psi(t)\right>&s=3$
```

but

```
$latex \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$
```

or

```
$latex \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$
```

lead to errors in wordpress

```
Formula does not pass
```

One issue could be related to the markdown plugin which I fear is interfering with the markdown WP Editor.md. Is there a way to escape correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal, but I removed the plugin Markdown and used the option for markdown on the Jetpack. Now I am able to do .md and latex in one file.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues but switched my setup and used 'MathML block' which solved the issues I was having, Not sure if will do the same for you but thought I would share.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).